# Retrieving tag from IBOutletCollection of UIButtons

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray, iboutletcollection

I have an IBOutletCollection of UIButtons. What is the most efficient way of retrieving the tags of any index in my mutableArray of buttons.

```
@property(retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSMutableArray *emptySpaces;
```

This is how my buttons are declared

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *position1;
```

Ive tried the following. What is it I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```
if(emptySpaces[0].tag == 1){

}
```

Or

```
 if([emptySpaces objectAtIndex:0].tag == 1){

  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your initial question, an `id` which is what NSMutableArray `-objectAtIndex:` returns, doesn't have a receiver named `tag`. You should first cast your result to a `UIButton` before sending the tag message. Like this: `((UIButton *)self.emptySpaces[0]).tag`

You could try something like this:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.emptySpaces) {
    if (button.tag == 1) {

    }
}
```